# Postgis - step in state load (loader_load_staged_data) is producing more columns in select than in insert

Tags: postgis

The loader_load_staged_data, called from the script generated for states by Loader_Generate_Script, is failing when attempting to insert faces data. The `uace20` column is present in the select but not in the insert. Is this a known issue / is there a workaround?

````
${PSQL} -c "SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower(NY_faces), lower(NY_faces));"

NOTICE:  INSERT INTO tiger_data.ny_faces(aiannhce,aiannhfp,anrcfp,atotal,blkgrpce,blkgrpce20,blockce20,cbsafp,cd111fp,cnectafp,comptyp,conctyfp,countyfp,countyfp20,cousubfp,csafp,elsdlea,intptlat,intptlon,lwflag,metdivfp,nctadvfp,nectafp,"offset",placefp,scsdlea,sldlst,sldust,statefp,statefp20,submcdfp,tblkgpce,tfid,the_geom,tractce,tractce20,trsubce,trsubfp,ttractce,unsdlea,zcta5ce) SELECT aiannhce,aiannhfp,anrcfp,atotal,blkgrpce,blkgrpce20,blockce20,cbsafp,cd118fp,cnectafp,comptyp,conctyfp,countyfp,countyfp20,cousubfp,csafp,elsdlea,intptlat,intptlon,lwflag,metdivfp,nctadvfp,nectafp,"offset",placefp,scsdlea,sldlst,sldust,statefp,statefp20,submcdfp,tblkgpce,tfid,the_geom,tractce,tractce20,trsubce,trsubfp,ttractce,uace20,unsdlea,zcta5ce20 FROM tiger_staging.ny_faces;
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: ...tractce20,trsubce,trsubfp,ttractce,uace20,unsdlea,zcta5ce20 ...
```                                                             ^
````